# Re-positioning/rotating a pseudo element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pseudo element(s) being created by code (.mask), and it's `positioned:absolute` at the bottom of a div with a background image. This is to make it look like there is an arrow/pointer at the bottom of the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/hunt0194/gu1sgotd/3/

I used `background-color:red;` instead of an image to make it simpler

I use `.mask` div  on `col-md-8` (Bootstrap 3 used to make two columns)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" style="background-image:url('...');">
        <div class="mask">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want it to point to the left instead of down. The code creates the two pieces which line up to make it look like a masked out arrow, I don't believe it creates the arrow itself. (I did not write this code so I'm not 100% sure).

NOTE: I have asked this question a few times before, and all the answers given have me making an arrow and placing it outside the div. Since I am using a background-image on the div and not a solid colour, I cannot do that.

visual aid. (red outlines just used to indicate div borders)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a design image how this is **supposed** to look...

Comment: Just insert a background image to see that the arrow is indeed a continuation of the image, and not just a colored triangle. If you do not want the mask itself to be visible, you should specify that in your question. (But I can't think of a way to do this with images of uncertain sizes. Even when the size is known, it would be a task that might exceed its own worth)

Comment: I added a visual aid to my post. The code doesn't make the triangle, it makes the two bars that for the triangle in between them. So it acts like a mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take things like positions ("left", "top", ...) and dimensions ("width", "height") and rotate them by 90 degrees, so these examples become "top", "right", ...) and ("height", "width"), and the same code still works:

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/5zoL1rrg/

```css
.indx-img {
 position: relative;
 padding: 16% 0;
 background-image:url(http://susancorso.com/seedsforsanctuary/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/box_placeholder.jpg);
}

.mask:before {
    border-top: 0 none;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    top: 0;
}
.mask:after {
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    bottom: 0;
}
.mask:before, .mask:after {
    border-left: 20px solid #000;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mask {
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="indx-img">
   <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So we don't actually need to rotate a pseudo element. Just tell it its new properties and you're all set.

Comment: Exactly! (Every other thread suggested I rotate the image, etc.) I tried switching values and properties, but just couldn't get it.  I'm going to try your code  as soon as I can, looks good. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)
Remember, if you would like to keep the old behavior as well for other containers, you might want to assign a class to the ones where you would like the exception to show, and overwrite the important values: [https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/mp705d7L/](https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/mp705d7L/)

Comment: That is what I want to to but running into problems. I want to keep original .mask values for mobile (containers stack so arrow needs to pint down) and use your code for screen. I just put original code in mediaQuery but something is screwing up alignment. Need to reset certain values or something

Comment: I updated the fiddle with a comment to clearly mark the section that lets the "left"-classed objects use the left arrow without changing the others. If you're still running onto problems, maybe the class you assigned has some other rules attached (quite likely if you literally used "left". you might replace those with "left-mask-arrow" to be safe)

Comment: My prob is that every one will have 'left' on it, then when in mobile screen sizes they will all need to go back to original '.mask' settings. Trying to figure out which values to reset (i know, top: auto; for .mask, etc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77738/discussion-between-ben-philipp-and-user3550879).